# Which font tables are required when embedding an OpenType font into a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, opentype

Table 126 of the PDF 1.7 spec explains how to embed fonts into PDF files.  For OpenType fonts the spec states "In addition to the 'CFF ' table, the font program must include the 'cmap' table" (see the excerpt below).  Does this mean that 'CFF ' and 'cmap' are the only two tables required?

Experimentally I found that just including 'CFF ' and 'cmap' works with Acrobat Reader, but Preview on MacOS seems to also require the 'head' and 'maxp' tables.  Are these four tables enough for every viewer?

[image: an excerpt of the PDF spec]

Comment: You've quoted ISO 32000-1. ISO 32000-2 (both the 2017 and the 2020 version) still essentially contain the same information. https://pdf-issues.pdfa.org/32000-2-2020/index.html also does not introduce changes. Thus, apparently in the situation of the third (and the second) item in the list quoted, only 'CFF ' and 'cmap' are required. As anyone can implement a new viewer with its own quirks, there is no way to answer *"Are these four tables enough for every viewer?"*

Comment: @mkl I agree, **every** was too big a word.  But I definitely want to cover viewers as mainstream as Apple's preview.  I also note that there is a bit of ambiguity.  For TrueType the list says "the font program must include these tables: ...".  In comparison, the OpenType phrase seems a bit vague to me.  Does this really mean that it's only two tables?  Or does it mean "CFF " and "cmap" in addition to another list I have missed elsewhere?

Comment: Considering your experimental findings I would assume "CFF " and "cmap" alone suffice. On the other hand I'm not a font expert. You might want to create an issue on https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf-issues to request clarification in this regard from people from the PDF association and the ISO PDF committee.

Comment: @jochen some time has passed, but it would still be a good idea to file that issue and then also give its link in the post so that should there ever be an answer by the people who actually write spec, this post can be given an answer here, too.